# Calling a base class constructor in derived class after some code block in derived constructor

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, c#-5.0

```
public class bar
{
   public bar(list<int> id, String x, int size, byte[] bytes)
   {
     ...
   }
}

public class Foo: Bar
{
    public Foo(list<int> id, String x, someEnumType y):
     base(id, x, sizeof(someEnumType), y)
    {
        //some functionality
    }
}
```

As you see in the above code I need to convert someEnumType to byte array type before calling base class constructor. Is there a way to do it? Something like:

```
public class Foo: Bar
{
    public Foo(list<int> id, String x, someEnumType y)
    {
        //someEnumType to byte array
        base(...)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a method in your derived class and call it....

```
public class bar
{
   public bar(list<int> id, String x, int size, byte[] bytes)
   {
     ...
   }
}

public class Foo: Bar
{
    public Foo(list<int> id, String x, someEnumType y):
     base(id, x, sizeof(someEnumType), Convert(y))
    {
        //some functionality
    }

    public static byte[] Convert(SomeEnumType type)
    {
        // do convert
    }
}
```

Comment: u are right .. i updated answer